# Inserting a new column with openpyxl removes previous column width adjustment?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Below is a snippet out of my code thats supposed to create a new E column and insert the current time in E1.

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\daani\Documents\Programmering\automate_online-materials')
if 'ownUpdatedProduce.xlsx' in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    print('Updated excel file found. Updating this one')
    mainFileName = 'ownUpdatedProduce.xlsx'
else:
    print('Updated excel file not found. Creating one')
    mainFileName = 'produceSales.xlsx'


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(mainFileName)
sheet = wb[(wb.sheetnames[0])]
sheet.insert_cols(idx=5, amount=1)
sheet.column_dimensions['E'].width = 19
sheet['E1'] = currentTime
sheet['E1'].font = capitalFont
```

After that it does some stuff to the file and saves it. The only thing that does not work as intended is what happens to the E column. It was intended to create a new column on the fifth position (E) and adjust its size to 19 then insert current date as bold text whenever the script is run. It does that perfectly the first time its run (when the updated file does not exist). But on consecutive runs, as it inserts a new column the previously created ones get their width readjusted back to excels default. So whatever was on E column on first run is now on F column with a much narrower width. I've added a picture of the excel file after 3 runs to try and clarify what i mean.

[image]

Comment: When you insert or delete rows or columns in openpyxl you're only dealing with the cells. Any changes to the dimensions have to be handled manually.

Answer (score -1):

As Charlie Clark commented, one needs to back fill the widths. Apparently, insert_cols in openpyxl does not change the map between the column letter and the width. Respectively, the widths are shifted by one, if one column is inserted.

```
import openpyxl

mainFileName = 'produceSales.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(mainFileName)
ws = wb.active

col = 5
ws.insert_cols(col,1)
for i in range(ws.max_column-1,col,-1):
    l = openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter(i) # Get the next column letter
    m = openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter(i-1) # Get the previous column letter
    ws.column_dimensions[l].width = ws.column_dimensions[m].width        

col_letter = openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter(col)
sheet.column_dimensions[col_letter].width = 19
wb.save(mainFileName)
```